# Rasterize the full area of a polygon, not only midpoints, using R

Tags: raster, r, polygon, rasterization

The default function in raster::rasterize is to see if a point is within a polygon and if yes, make a cell. This results in that some of the outer parts of the polygon is not covered by the new raster. 
Is it possible to use rasterize (or fasterize or whatever) in a way, so that the entire polygon is covered?

Comment: You could maybe buffer the polygons by half-a-cell and then rasterise, or rasterise and then buffer the raster by a cell using a "grow" operation. Alternatively you have to form a rectangle for each of your raster cells and do a load of polygons-raster intersections...

Answer (score -1):

Make a fishnet, select cells in the fishnet that overlap the polygon, and then rasterize the cells selected. ['Fishnet'](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/how-create-fishnet-works.htm) is the ESRI term for it. You can use the SF package to do it in R, as per the answer in this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225157/generate-rectangular-fishnet-or-vector-grid-cells-shapefile-in-r).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by fishnet?